# table view cannot be displayed on device

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am developing iOS app where I want to display table content one my device.but unable fetch and display...but contents are being displayed on console view.
I am using json getmethod() to fetch the details
also using view controller and view table and swift language

```
import UIKit

class UpdateSheetManagementViewController:
UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, WebserviceDelegate {

    //var FinalArray = [[String:Any]]()

//    class func instantiateFromStoryboard() -> UpdateSheetManagementViewController {
//        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Management", bundle: nil)
//        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: self)) as! UpdateSheetManagementViewController
//    }

    @IBOutlet weak var managementTableView: UITableView!
    var controllerType : String!
    var array = [[String : Any]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = controllerType
        updatesheetWebserviceCall()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
//        updatesheetWebserviceCall()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 320.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
//        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UpdateSheetManagementTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! UpdateSheetManagementTableViewCell
    let cellIdentifier : String = "UpdateSheetManagementTableViewCell";
        let cell : UpdateSheetManagementTableViewCell =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! UpdateSheetManagementTableViewCell
        let dict = array[indexPath.section]
        cell.classname.text = dict["Cls_Name"] as? String
        cell.dateFrom.text = dict["Date_From"] as? String
        cell.date_To.text = dict["Date_To"] as? String
        cell.downloadButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.downloadButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onDownloadButtonClicked(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }


    func onDownloadButtonClicked(button : UIButton) {
        let postion = button.tag
        let data = array[postion]
        let attachment = data["Attachment"] as? String
        if(attachment != nil && attachment!.characters.count > 0){
            let userid = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: USER_ID)
            let finalString = "https://skillskool.mycit.co.in/PagesParentApp/Today-ClassNotes.aspx?FilePath=" + attachment! + "&UserId=" + userid! + "&PageName=UpdateSheet"
            let url = URL(string: finalString)
            if(url != nil){
                UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            }

        }

    }

    func updatesheetWebserviceCall() {

        let str = ""
        let webClass = WebserviceClass()
        webClass.delegate = self
        webClass.fireRequest(functionName: "MgmtUpdateSheet.php", requestString: str, view: view)
    }

    func webserviceDidFinishWith(response: [String : Any], functionName: String) {
        parseUpdateSheetWebservice(response: response)
    }

    func parseUpdateSheetWebservice(response : [String : Any]) {
        let arr = response["homework"] as? [[String : Any]]
        if(arr != nil){
           // array.removeAll()
            self.array.append(contentsOf: arr!)
           // managementTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `managementTableView.reloadData()` after updating the data and make sure to set the delegate and datasource in either view controller or storyboard

Comment: remove this    @IBOutlet weak var managementTableView: UITableView! ... you don't need it you can get tableView directly. Make sure your receive the data from the web service and your data in array is stored properly. It's better if you use Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set in `viewDidLoad`

```
managementTableView.dataSource = self
```

and un comment `managementTableView.reloadData()`

```
 func parseUpdateSheetWebservice(response : [String : Any]) {
    let arr = response["homework"] as? [[String : Any]]
    if(arr != nil){
       // array.removeAll()
        self.array.append(contentsOf: arr!)
      DispatchQueue.main.async { 
        managementTableView.reloadData() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set tableview delegate and datasource in viewDidLoad and reload tableview in web service response.

```
// set tableview delegate and datasource in viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = controllerType
    managementTableView.dataSource = self
    //managementTableView.delegate = self
    updatesheetWebserviceCall()
}


// reload tableview upon web service response
func parseUpdateSheetWebservice(response : [String : Any]) {
    let arr = response["homework"] as? [[String : Any]]
    if(arr != nil){
       // array.removeAll()
        self.array.append(contentsOf: arr!)
        self.managementTableView.reloadData()

        /* 
        // or reload table using main queue, if you web service operation is in background queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.managementTableView.reloadData()
        }
        */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `delegate` and `datasource` connections are missed, please add the following code in `viewDidLoad` function:

```
self.managementTableView.delegate = self;
self.managementTableView.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, you need to set `tableview` dataSource and delegate and after loading data you also need to reload data.

```
self.managementTableView.delegate = self;

self.managementTableView.datasource = self;
```

Reload data:

```
 self.array.append(contentsOf: arr!)
 self.managementTableView.reloadData()
```